# Kubernetes Ingress Address is missing in GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have already install the K8 controllers needed from ingress, however after executing `kubectl delete all --all` it seem to have deleted something i should have not deleted.

Output where the address is missing:

```
my-ingress   <none>   *                 80      15m
```

INgress file:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: questionbankrestapi
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /discounted
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: questionbankrestapi
            port:
              number: 80
```

I have installed GKE Controllers using:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.1.1/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml
```

And I have also done the bindings:

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding cluster-admin-binding   --clusterrole cluster-admin   --user $(gcloud config get-value account)
```

Here is the describe ing output:

```
Name:             my-ingress
Labels:           <none>
Namespace:        default
Address:          
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (10.4.0.6:8080)
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  *           
              /*            questionbankrestapi:80 (10.4.0.10:4000)
              /discounted   questionbankrestapi:80 (10.4.0.10:4000)
Annotations:  <none>
Events:
  Type     Reason  Age                 From                     Message
  ----     ------  ----                ----                     -------
  Normal   Sync    84s (x4 over 20m)   loadbalancer-controller  Scheduled for sync
  Warning  Sync    83s (x20 over 19m)  loadbalancer-controller  Error syncing to GCP: error running backend syncing routine: error ensuring health check: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value for field 'resource.timeoutSec': '15'. TimeoutSec should be less than checkIntervalSec., invalid
```

Kubernetes Version:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"23", GitVersion:"v1.23.3", GitCommit:"816c97ab8cff8a1c72eccca1026f7820e93e0d25", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-01-25T21:25:17Z", GoVersion:"go1.17.6", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.6-gke.1503", GitCommit:"2c7bbda09a9b7ca78db230e099cf90fe901d3df8", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-02-18T03:17:45Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.9b7", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
WARNING: version difference between client (1.23) and server (1.21) exceeds the supported minor version skew of +/-1
```

Ran the Ready Check, seems ok too:

```
+]ping ok
[+]log ok
[+]etcd ok
[+]informer-sync ok
[+]poststarthook/start-kube-apiserver-admission-initializer ok
[+]poststarthook/generic-apiserver-start-informers ok
[+]poststarthook/priority-and-fairness-config-consumer ok
[+]poststarthook/priority-and-fairness-filter ok
[+]poststarthook/start-apiextensions-informers ok
[+]poststarthook/start-apiextensions-controllers ok
[+]poststarthook/crd-informer-synced ok
[+]poststarthook/bootstrap-controller ok
[+]poststarthook/rbac/bootstrap-roles ok
[+]poststarthook/scheduling/bootstrap-system-priority-classes ok
[+]poststarthook/priority-and-fairness-config-producer ok
[+]poststarthook/start-cluster-authentication-info-controller ok
[+]poststarthook/aggregator-reload-proxy-client-cert ok
[+]poststarthook/start-kube-aggregator-informers ok
[+]poststarthook/apiservice-registration-controller ok
[+]poststarthook/apiservice-status-available-controller ok
[+]poststarthook/kube-apiserver-autoregistration ok
[+]autoregister-completion ok
[+]poststarthook/apiservice-openapi-controller ok
[+]shutdown ok
readyz check passed
```

Comment: i can guess a bit, but not 100% sure. Please let us know, which k8s version you're running. Also check if this version of nginx ingress controller is working with the k8s version. Instead of applying the changes, what is generated out of a helm chart, you could better use the nginx ingress helm chart immediately.

Comment: Updated the version. The prb is that i was getting address earlier, now it stopped working after "kubectl delete all --all"

Comment: Ok. At least the ingress-nginx version and your server version should be compatible.
While deleting everything inside your cluster you may run the command `kubectl get --raw='/readyz?verbose'` it shows some health information about your k8s api endpoints

Comment: Sounds a bit, like something is misconfigured. As far as i can see, it shouldn't be the ingress. I guess, because you were deleting everything, you accidently deleted a kube-system specific resource.  Error syncing to GCP: error running backend syncing routine: error ensuring health check: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value for field 'resource.timeoutSec': '15'. TimeoutSec should be less than checkIntervalSec., invalid

Comment: Even after deleting the cluster, I tried recreating a completly new cluster, the issue persist. I believe it is do with something that got configured.

Comment: Added the out for the readyz check.

Comment: Ok, surprising me a bit. I'm expecting the rest of the cluster works fine. Did you try to deploy something else? Do you run into issues then?

Answer (score 0):

If you ran the `kubectl delete all --all` command then you deleted everything from your current namespace like Pods, Services and Statefulsets, however *RoleBindings*, *ServiceAccounts* and *NetworkPolicies* were not.

For that reason, I suggest you verify if your [Load Balancer services](https://console.cloud.google.com/projectselector/kubernetes/discovery) and your [Health Check time](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-checks?_ga=2.150253750.-1418735072.1639493729&_gac=1.58231512.1644874296.Cj0KCQiAmKiQBhClARIsAKtSj-lB_WBXa-9wl6d_L82biDdigqRuRUo73tv-hc_H_VnoZyQZsQoCb3MaAix5EALw_wcB#list-hcs) values were set to `15 seconds`; this is the default value. **If yes, please set it to 60 seconds because the value of the timeout must be less than or equal to the interval**. Additionally, if the [ingress](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress) was deleted; this could also be the cause for the service IP not to be shown.

You can review this in the [Services & ingress](https://console.cloud.google.com/projectselector/kubernetes/discovery) option in the [Kubernetes Engine](https://console.cloud.google.com/projectselector/kubernetes/) GCP console menu, so **if this was deleted please try to recreate the ingress** [from scratch](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/load-balance-ingress#creating_an_ingress).

Attached below is an example on how to correctly set the backend config health check:

```
    healthCheck:
    checkIntervalSec: 10
    timeoutSec: 10
    port: 80
    requestPath: /discounted
    type: HTTPS
    securityPolicy:
    name: your-policy-restricted
    sessionAffinity:
    affinityType: NONE
    timeoutSec: 60
```

Comment: Can you also post your Service spec as well as the BackendConfig?  The error message indicates that the healthCheck section of your BackendConfig is invalid.  See https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-features#direct_health

Comment: Also, not sure if you really wanted to use nginx Ingress, but even though you installed the  nginx Ingress controller, you are still using the default GCE Ingress.